# SIP calls POSTing StatusCallback when call ends even though no StatusCallback URL is configured

Tags: sip, twilio

When SIP calls end, the last request that was POSTed to my app gets POSTed again, slightly modified, but with the params that the Twilio docs indicate will be included in a call StatusCallback POST. This is doubly weird because I don't have a StatusCallback URL configured!

So ...an example. The environment (all URLs are https):

- Twilio SIP endpoint: `test-myaccount.sip.twilio.com`
- Voice URL (POST): `myapp.myserver.com/twilioapp`
- Fallback URL (GET): `s3.amazonaws.com/somebucket/twilioerror.xml` *(can't imagine that's relevant, but I mention it in case it tips anyone off to weird side effects)*
- StatusCallback URL (POST): blank

The call flow:

1a. Call made to SIP endpoint - Twilio sends request to TwiML app server:

> ```
> POST myapp.myserver.com/twilioapp
> ```

1b. TwiML app responds:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Response>
>   <Say language="en-US" voice="alice">May the fourth be with you!</Say>
>   <Redirect>myapp.myserver.com/twilioapp/secondstep?actualdate=20140503</Redirect>
> </Response>
> ```

2a. Twilio plays the TTS speech, then POSTs back to the app server (per the Redirect verb):

> ```
> POST myapp.myserver.com/twilioapp/secondstep?actualdate=20140503
> ```

2b. The app server responds:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <Response>
>   <Say language="en-US" voice="alice">Whoops, wrong date. Goodbye!</Say>
>   <Hangup />
> </Response>
> ```

3a. Here's the funkiness I'm seeing - Twilio is then POSTing another request:

> ```
> POST myapp.myserver.com/twilioapp/secondstep/?actualdate=20140503
> ```

Note (a) that the POST is to the last URL that Twilio posted to and (b) a trailing slash has been added to the URL, before the querystring params.

Params that are sent with that final POST:

```
AccountSid: <MyAccountSid>
Caller: sip:55512345678@169.0.0.0
CallStatus: completed
Duration: 1
Called: sip:test-myaccount.sip.twilio.com
To: sip:test-myaccount.sip.twilio.com
CallDuration: 22
CallSid: <TheCallSid>
From: sip:55512345678@169.0.0.0
Direction: inbound
ApiVersion: 2010-04-01
```

More weird: both Duration and CallDuration are included in the POST params - Duration in (rounded up) minutes, CallDuration in seconds.

So - I have no idea what's up. I've got a support ticket in, but haven't heard back in several days; figured while I was waiting on the Twilio code spelunkers to work their magic I'd ping the community and see if anyone else has noticed this behavior too.

Answer (score 0):

Twilo Evangelist here.

I just spoke with one of our customer support team members and it looks like we have an issue reported for this behavior.  She should be reaching out to you shortly to give you a more detailed update.

If we identify a work-around, we'll make sure to update this SO post with those details.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any updates? My last conversation with twilio had them telling me to just put something in for the StatusCallback URL so that the phantom StatusCallback POSTs wouldn't hit my own servers :/ Not exactly ideal...

Comment: Hey Robert.  Did you receive an email from someone on our customer support team?  If you did I would suggest reaching back out to them and they can give you an update.